# Is this a rational or irrational number?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

It is given that $$z=\sqrt\frac{\sqrt{3x+1}}{\sqrt{3x-1}}$$ How does one find whether $z$ is a rational or irrational number?

Comment: does the first sqrt contain all of the subsequent expression? what is x?

Comment: An expression isn't a statement, so we can't really say "It is given that [expression]." (At least, we can't do so sensibly.) What are you trying to say, here? Also, is your expression supposed to be $$\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{3x+1}}{\sqrt{3x-1}}}?$$ That would be `\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{3x+1}}{\sqrt{3x-1}}}` to get the formatting.

Comment: First sqrt contains full expression and x is variable letter 'x'

Comment: I edited to apply MathJax and formulated the question. Is my understanding correct and does the MathJax formula reflect what you wanted to express?

Comment: Yes, thanks for that.

Comment: when i asked "what is x?", i meant what is the domain of x. it's very hard to answer your question if we don't have any constraints on x. See the Erick Wong's comment to the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

By sqaring twice we get:

$$
z^4 = \frac{3x+1}{3x-1}
$$

To get a rational solution we are looking for two squared squares
with a difference of two:

$$\begin{align}
3x+1 & = K^4 \\
3x-1 & = L^4
\end{align}$$

With $L = K -1$ we get the smallest distance possible:

$$K^4 - (K-1)^4 = 2$$

This equation has no integer solution for $K$.
Therefore, no rational value for $z$ can exist.

---

**Update:**

> As pointed out in the comments, $x = 17 / 45$ is in fact a solution.
>   So, what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: This solution is incomplete: we don't know that $(3x+1)/(3x-1)$ is in lowest terms.  Of course, the bigger omission is the OP's: nowhere in the question does it specify whether $x$ is integer, rational, or maybe even real.

Comment: I am not veey sure but it is one of the problem for ninth grade exams on number system where they have to identify this is whether rational or irrational.

Comment: $x = 17/45$ gives $z = 2$.